# Sending Keystrokes to selenium RC to press continue button in a security warning dialog box

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-rc

How to send key strokes like <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to Selenium RC to click on the `Continue` button of the security warning dialog box in Firefox?

> Although this page is encrypted, the information you have entered is
>   to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could easily be read by
>   a third party.

Or if there is any other way to click on the `Continue` button, that would also be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution, not sure if it would be useful for you:

Instead of trying to click on the OK button on the dialog, it may be easier to prevent it appearing by changing settings on your firefox to tell it not to display that specific warning. I think the settings for that could be accessed by typing about:config in the address bar of your firefox, and then typing security.warn in field filter. The one you're looking for is probably one of them!

Comment: @Ross Patterson Thanks. I edited the post after your feedback to suggest an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not with just Selenium RC.  The usual answer for Windows environments is to use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com).

Comment: Thanks Ross Patterson and Ashkan Aryan for your valuable answers.
Ashkan Aryan,currently all the security warnings starting with 'security.warn*.*' under about:config page are disabled i.e the value is set to 'false'.

Please help me to resolve this issue.